# FlaskMigrate compare_type

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I am using flask migrate and I want to change the type of one if my columns, but I don't know if my previous data, in my case integers will be converted to in my case floating point numbers. So I would like to know what would happen with my previous data of that column.

Comment: This is going to depend on how your database handles the type conversion. In general the data will be converted as best as possible, but the best way to know is to do a test with a throwaway table.

Comment: Alright, thank you.